# is it possible to change customer tags through Shopify script editor?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am trying to add new tags on customer based on shipping address at the time of purchase through Shopify script editor. Went through this [doc](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/script-editor/shopify-scripts) but didn't get anything related to it.

Comment: Nopes, as per Shopify scripts currently have 3 scopes Line item scripts, Shipping scripts and Payment Scripts. which means there is no way to update the customer using scripts.

Comment: You need to use custom build app to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Shopify Flow. If you have Plus, which you seem to, Flow can alter customer records based on Orders.